# Action Bar's items overlapping app's name?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

As you guys can see, my app's name has been overlapped by Action bar's items. I have only two items in action bar.
Is it possible to show only one item there so that it couldn't overlap the app name and rest of the item/s in overflow menu(the default behavior..)?
Wondering why its not sensing the app name and arranging its items accordingly?

Edit (actionbar.xml):

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    >
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:title="@string/email"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
</item>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ActionBarSherlock? I believe I had a similar problem until I changed my theme in my androidManifest.xml to be derived from Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow

Add to AndroidManifest.xml under application tag

android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow"